# How to deactivate slick slider in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, shopify, slick.js

I have a Shopify Debut Theme store and I would like to deactivate the product Slick Slider Thumbnail when the page is viewed on mobile. My desktop/tablet version has a flat layout like this [[image]], but it becomes weird and the format messes up when the slick slider is activated on mobile version [[image]]. I have tried many ways to deactivate the Slick Slider, but nothing has worked, I just want the mobile version to have the same layout as the desktop/tablet one (flat layout), can anyone help me on this, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, only you have to set in your slick options the width for reponsive where you want to disable the slider:

```
    $(".slider").slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows:false,
          responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 676, //YOUR MOBILE WIDTH
              settings: "unslick" //DISABLE SLIDER
            }
          ]
    });
```